# Somar array em moeda javascript

Tags: javascript, parser, conversão

Preciso de uma ajuda pra converter e somar campos formatados como moeda vindo neste formato "1.568,78"

Tenho um código que soma um array de parcelas e confere se é igual ao falor total da fatura que consegui aqui após várias consultas em respostas de usuarios, e funciona perfeitamente com numeros inteiros, mas quando digito o numero formatado em reais ele nao soma:

```
var quant = document.getElementsByName("valor[]");
function somarValores(){
var valor_fatura = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor_fatura').value);
var soma = 0;
var soma = [].reduce.call(quant, function (somatorio, el) {
    return somatorio + parseInt(el.value, 10) || 0;
}, 0);
if(soma != valor_fatura){
 alert('Valor não confere. Fatura='+valor_fatura+' - Parcelas='+soma+'');
 return false;
}

}
```

Presumo então que tenho que converter as variáveis "quant" e "valor_fatura" para o formato 1568.78 antes de calcular porque como está ele arredonda para numeros inteiros e desconsidera os centavos ocasionando erro na minha validação

Comment: Eu comecei a escrever uma resposta mas depois vi o tamanho da responsabilidade. Basicamente, você vai ter que fazer uma função que substitui as vírgulas por pontos e vice-versa e depois usar o parseFloat. O problema é que Javascript não tem um "replaceAll". Os substitutos incluem usar expressões regulares, mas isso traz o perigo das entradas que contém meta-caracteres (caracteres especiais de expressões regulares). Daí você teria que fazer também um pré-tratamento da entrada pra evitar isso. Ou seja, vai dar um trabalhozinho. Se você seguir essa dica, publique aqui pra gente sua solução. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Remova o caracter ponto (.)
2. Substitua o caracter vírgula (,) por ponto (.)

```js
str = '1.568,78901';
str = str.replace(/[.]/g, '');
str = str.replace(/[,]/g, '.');
console.log(str);
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = str;


/**
Uma situação muito perigosa, inclusive citada num dos comentários, consiste em remover o ponto e a vírgula e dividir por 100. 
Isso não é seguro pois se trabalharmos com casas decimais maior ou menor que 2 casas, retornará um número errado.
*/
str = '1.568,78901';
str = str.replace(/[.,]/g, '');
str = parseInt(str) / 100;
console.log(str);
document.getElementById('foo2').innerHTML = 'cuidado... o resultado é errado: '+str;
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<br />
<div id="foo2"></div>
```

Para efetuar operações matemáticas, sempre utilize parseInt() ou parsetFloat() para converter as strings para um formato numérico próprio para cálculos.

Os nomes das funções são sugestivos "Int" para números inteiros e "Float" é para números flutuantes (com casas decimais).

Um exemplo mais completo, convertendo os números e realizando uma operação matemática:

```js
function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/
  number = (number + '')
    .replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
  var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
    prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
    sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
    dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
    s = '',
    toFixedFix = function(n, prec) {
      var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
      return '' + (Math.round(n * k) / k)
        .toFixed(prec);
    };
  // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
  s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n))
    .split('.');
  if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
  }
  if ((s[1] || '')
    .length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || '';
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1)
      .join('0');
  }
  return s.join(dec);
}


function floatFilter(str)
{
    str = str.replace(/[.]/g, '');
    str = str.replace(/[,]/g, '.');
    return parseFloat(str);
}

var n1 = '1.568,78901';
var n2 = '5.311';
var sum = floatFilter(n1) + floatFilter(n2);
document.getElementById('foo3').innerHTML = n1+' + '+n2+' = '+sum+' ou ('+number_format(sum, 5, ',', '.')+')';
```

```html
<div id="foo3"></div>
```

obs: A função `number_format()` é do projeto PHPJS.org: http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/

É um projeto que traduz funbções PHP para JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Galera, as dicas me ajudaram muito. Consegui resolver retirando a pontuação da string e usando o parseFloat dentro do proprio código pra não ficar com um código imenso.

```
var quant = document.getElementsByName("valor[]");
function somarValores(){
var valor_fatura = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor_fatura').value.replace('.','').replace(',','.'));
var soma = 0;
var soma = [].reduce.call(quant, function (somatorio, el) {
    return somatorio + parseFloat(el.value.replace('.','').replace(',','.'), 10) || 0;
}, 0);
if(soma != valor_fatura){
var diferenca = soma - valor_fatura;
$("#lcto_mostraerro").append("Valor não confere. Há uma diferença de "+parseFloat(diferenca)+"");
return false;
}    
}
```

Primeiro inclui o parseFloat no inicio da string e retiro a pontuação com replace ".replace('.','').replace(',','.')".

Pra dar uma incrementada usei **.append** pra mostrar o erro dentro de uma div ao invés do **alert**

Answer (score 0):

Use parseFloat() do JavaScript. Se a sua string vem como "1.568,78" (exemplo). Você deve fazer assim:

```js
parseFloat("1.568,78") //1568.78
```

Comment: Continua arredondando "var valor_fatura = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor_fatura').value);"

Comment: Deve ser porque você está passando parseInt() mais abaixo.

Comment: substitui por parseFloat abaixo e também não resolveu

Comment: Você pode remover os pontos e as vírgulas de cada valor e dividir por 100. `var str = "1.568,78"; str = str.replace(/[,.]/g, ''); alert(parseInt(str)/100) ;`

Comment: OP, tem uma ótima e simples alternativa do Battisti no link a seguir. É a última função moeda2Float(): https://battisti.wordpress.com/2007/03/08/arredondar-formatando-e-desformatando-valores-em-javascript/